# Regular expression for separating words by uppercase letters and numbers

Tags: objective-c, regex

I was wondering if anyone might know what the regular expression would be to turn this:

> West4thStreet

into this:

> West 4th Street

I'm going to add the spaces to the string in Objective-C.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly where you want to put in spaces, but try something like `[a-z.-][^a-z .-]` and then put a space between the two characters in each match.

Comment: Hey Jeremiah, that Regex worked, but I'm having trouble adding in the whitespaces in objC inbetween the letters.  Here is what I have so far:   

`NSString *myText2 = @"West4thStreet";`
`NSString *regexString2 = @"([a-z.-][^a-z .-])";`
`for(NSString *match2 in [myText2 componentsMatchedByRegex:regexString2 capture:1L]) {`
`NSString *myString = [myText2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:match2 withString:@" "];`
`NSLog(@"Prints out: %@",myString);`
`// Prints out: Wes thStreet`
`// Prints out: West4t treet` 
}`

Answer (score 2):

Something like this perl regex substitution would put a space before each *group* of capital letters or numbers.  (You'd want to trim space before the string in this case also.) I assume you don't want it to break up eg: 45thStreet to 4 5th Street

Letters I'm less certain of.

```
s/([A-Z]+|[0-9]+)/ \1/g
```

I created a pattern to not match the beginning of the line for my personal amusement:

```
s/([^\^])([A-Z]+|[0-9]+)/\1 \2/g
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work, if all your strings truly match the format of your example:

```
([A-Z][a-z]+)(\d+[a-z]+)([A-Z][a-z]+)
```

You can then separate the groups with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to not use RegExKit and use code to loop through each character in the string and insert a space after each capital letter or after first decimal..

```
NSMutableString *myText2 = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"The1stTest"];
bool isNumber=false;
for(int x=myText2.length-1;x>1;x--)
{
    bool isUpperCase = [[NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[myText2 characterAtIndex:x]];
    bool isLowerCase = [[NSCharacterSet lowercaseLetterCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[myText2 characterAtIndex:x]];
    if([[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[myText2 characterAtIndex:x]])
        isNumber = true;
    if((isUpperCase || isLowerCase) && isNumber)
    {
          [myText2 insertString:@" " atIndex:x+1];
          isNumber=false;
    }
    if(isUpperCase)
        [myText2 insertString:@" " atIndex:x];
}
NSLog(@"%@",myText2);  // Output: "The 1st Test"
```