# Why do not want to work? There are options?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nsstring

```
NSString *firstNameLastName =@"DavidMatvienko";
NSArray *listItems = [firstNameLastName componentsSeparatedByString:@"David , Matvienko"];
NSLog(@"listItems %@", listItems);
```

It should be concluded in NSLog: David Matvienko; David; Matvienko. Why do not want to work? There are options?

Comment: str1 = @“David”
str2 = @“Matvienko”
str3 = @“David Matvienko"

Comment: Are you sure the input is correct? What is the `input string` that you want to extract the forename and surname out of!? is it "DavidMatvienko" or "David Matvienko" or "David, Matvienko"???

Comment: @DavidDavid str3 =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", str1,str2];
 [NSString class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-SW21) this link will be useful to you

Comment: @Banto25 Yes, I need to do from DavidMatvienko David Matvienko. Prompt method if you know please ..

Comment: @DavidDavid you should go with regular expressions and then split accordingly and then merge

Comment: @Banto25, Do can not be divided by large letters?

Comment: @Banto25 How to do it?

Comment: @DavidDavid refer to this question [Regular expression for separating words by uppercase letters and numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215623/regular-expression-for-separating-words-by-uppercase-letters-and-numbers)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
NSString *firstNameLastName =@"David, Matvienko";  
NSArray *listItems = [firstNameLastName componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
NSLog(@"listItems %@", listItems);
```

You mixed parameters.

`componentsSeparatedByString` will split the string (here `firstNameLastName`) by what has been supplied as parameter. So it works as designed. If that is not what you intended you should try to make your question clearer.

Comment: I need to create a string of writing merged. Maybe I chose not true test method?

Comment: Yes, I need to do from DavidMatvienko David Matvienko. Prompt method if you know please ..

Comment: You mean you have @"DavidMatvienko" and want from that two strings @"David" and @"Matvienko"?

Answer (score 0):

the code you are looking is this

```
NSString *firstNameLastName =@"David Matvienko";
NSArray *listItems = [firstNameLastName componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSLog(@"listItems %@", listItems);
```

this will output:

```
listItems (
 David
 Matvienko
)
```

basically the method `componentsSeparatedByString:` will split a string given based on the seperator

Comment: I need to create a string of writing merged. Maybe I chose not true test method?

Comment: @DavidDavid can you explain your requirement with an example input and output

Comment: Yes, I need to do from DavidMatvienko David Matvienko. Prompt method if you know please ..

Comment: How to do it? I was a little did not understand

Answer (score 0):

You are completely misunderstanding what componentsSeparatedByString does.

The argument to componentsSeparatedByString is the separator that would be found between components of a string. For example

```
[@"Jim,Joe,James" componentsSeparatedByString:@","]
```

finds that there is a comma between Jim and Joe and a comma between Joe and James, so the result is an array @[@"Jim", @"Joe", @"James"].

You are using @"David , Matvienko" as the separator string. If your string was @"1David, Matvienko2David, Matvienko3" then the method would find that there is @"David, Matvienko" between @"1" and @"2", and between @"2" and @"3", so the result would be @[@"1", @"2", @"3"].

Since your string doesn't contain that substring, you will get an array with the original string.

And whoever asks you to split @"DavidMatvienko" into first and last name is rather daft. Try splitting "DeForestKelley" and "LeonardDeCaprio" into first and last name. Information has been lost that you cannot recover.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString* stringToTest = @"DavidMatvienko";
NSMutableString* resultString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:stringToTest];
NSCharacterSet *upperCaseSet = [NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet];
NSRange upperCaseRange = [stringToTest rangeOfCharacterFromSet: upperCaseSet options:NSBackwardsSearch];
if (upperCaseRange.location != NSNotFound) {
    [resultString insertString:@" " atIndex:upperCaseRange.location]; }
NSLog(@"%@", resultString);
```

Comment: This will fail with a name like "GeorgeMcFly".